# The default profile that i have put in the image field doesn't work in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a Custom User model which has an image field, I have as well added a default option and have given a default option but the user doesn't seem to be using the default option anytime I render it onto the templates.

I have observed that only when I add an image onto it, it works but it doesn't use the default if there is not image in it.

This is the file structure/directory in case I am making some mistakes there
[image]

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

    # CUSTOM USER FIELDS
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/users', blank=True, null=True, default='images/users/profile-pixs.png')
```

views.py

```
def Register(request):
    title = "Create a new Account"

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
        telephone = request.POST.get('telephone')
        country = request.POST.get('country')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        image = request.POST.get('image')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')

        user = User.objects.create_user(firstname=firstname, password=password1, 
            email=email, lastname=lastname, telephone=telephone, country=country, image=image)
        user.save()
        messages.success(request, "You have successfully created an account")
        return redirect('login')

    return render(request, 'auth/register.html', {"title":title})
```

templates.html

```
<div class="image">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="{{request.user.image.url}}" alt="John Doe" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

because django is looking you you default image in you media dir and what i can see you default image is in static directory copy and paste that image from static to media

```
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/users', default='profile-pixs.png')
```

then may be you are wondering why it save the file in that directory because you also load urlpattern of static directory

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

remove that then you can see you are also unabel to add profile from you side
and also move your photos saving directory to media dir for clean code
and also remove null and blank if you want a default photo because then it doesn't make sense then  and while requesting any file by request method django lookup for that file in your media dir
and yes also use

```
request.FILES['image']
```

in you views.py becuase image is type of file

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was using `request.POST.get('image')` for an image instead of using `request.FILES['image']`

I hope it helps someone also